# Infinite loop in DB2 JDBC driver

Tags: jdbc, db2, spring-batch

I'm using a Spring Batch, DB2 with JDBC v9.5 FP0 driver sometimes in any step where the process read from database I get the next error

> org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep execute Encountered an error executing the step
>                                   java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at java.util.HashMap.getEntry(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.HashMap.get(Unknown Source)
>     at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2DataStoreHelper.findMappingClass(DB2DataStoreHelper.java:529)
>     at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2DataStoreHelper.findMappingClass(DB2DataStoreHelper.java:545)
>     at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2DataStoreHelper.findMappingClass(DB2DataStoreHelper.java:545)
>
> ...
>
> infinite loop
>
> ...
>
> at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2DataStoreHelper.findMappingClass(DB2DataStoreHelper.java:545)
>     at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.DB2DataStoreHelper.findMappingClass(DB2DataStoreHelper.java:545)
>     at com.ibm.websphere.rsadapter.GenericDataStoreHelper.isConnectionError(GenericDataStoreHelper.java:433)
>     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.AdapterUtil.isConnectionError(AdapterUtil.java:1221)
>     at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcStatement.executeBatch(WSJdbcStatement.java:731)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$4.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:881)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:591)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:619)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:866)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.doExecuteBatchUpdateWithNamedParameters(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:287)
>     at org.springframework.jdbc.core.simple.SimpleJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(SimpleJdbcTemplate.java:261)
>     at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:177)

to solve i just rerun the process and everything goes fine, but the infinite loop is wierd. What can i do to avoid it?

Comment: Submit a bug. What is your question?

Comment: Edited. What can i do to avoid it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the problem is most probably in your job definition and business logic, can you provide those pieces

Comment: Most of the infinte loop i saw with Spring batch occurs when an ItemReader does not return null when all the items are read!  can you provide the implementation of your reader (if you provided a custom one)